# How to transform a unit root process to a stationary process?

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes, stationarity, brownian-motion

If a time series has a unit root, that can be modeled as discretized geometric Brownian motion,
then are there any ways to reduce the series to $\sim I(0)$? subject to the fact that no other time series $I(1)$ exists with which a linear combo of them would produce  $\sim I(0)$ via cointegration?

Without having to 1st-difference the series?

I even tried detrending the processes by eliminating the drift, and almost every possible way except for 1st-differencing, and the final process still ends up with a unit root.

Comment: First-differencing **is** the way to go if the series has a unit root.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a process has a unit root (a stochastic trend) and you want to make it stationary, you need to difference it. In other words, if $x_t\sim I(1)$, then $\Delta x_t:=x_t-x_{t-1} \sim I(0)$.

Without differencing you will not get rid of the unit root. E.g. subtracting a *deterministic* trend will not help because a unit root produces a *stochastic* trend; so you might end up with a combination of a stochastic and a deterministic trend in the end (the latter being introduced by subtracting a deterministic trend).

If you did not difference and the process truly has a unit root, then no wonder that whatever you tried has failed to produce a stationary transformation.

Answer (score 0):

taking the difference of the time series is NOT the only way to detrend a time series and to remove the unit root. the cointegration should be able to serve the same purpose.

Comment: Your answer is generally relevant but not helpful in this particular case. Read sentence no. 2 of the original post. It explicitly says cointegration cannot be invoked.